# iOS: Using both Facebook and Google, Google Plus sign in

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-plus, google-signin

Good morning,

I'm trying to implement the Facebook login (which is working fine) and also the google plus login in the same view. I'm following the guides from the official site (Google) but there is an issue between the Facebook button and the google plus button:

Facebook tells me to put the following code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

And also Google tells me to put the following:

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

And I can't have the same functions with the same name and I can't integrate one inside the other. That's why I need your help because I don't know how to deal with this issue between these guidelines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you  will have to check [url scheme]  before returning. Example code is below.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{ 
    NSLog("%@", [url scheme]); 

    if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:FACEBOOK_SCHEME]) 
    {  

        return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    }
    else if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:GOOGLE_PLUS_SCHEME]) 
    {  

        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]; 

    }
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks for your help Sreejith. Can you explain a little bit your code? Because that's my first app and I'm a little bit lost... Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @WirajPS If you just NSLog url scheme  or  just url in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

after performing facebook login or google login. you will be able to check url scheme after facebook login and google login will be different. hope you got what i mean. Please reply back if you have doubts..

Comment: Thanks again Sreejith. What I have to put in the 'FACEBOOK_SCHEME'?

Comment: Here  FACEBOOK_SCHEME and GOOGLE_PLUS_SCHEME are constants.FACEBOOK_SCHEME will be like fb appended with your facebook api key and GOOGLE_PLUS_SCHEME will be your bundle id. Hope you will get displayed when you NSLog `[url scheme]`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the version in **Swift**.

Firstly, you should understand how to see difference between Google and Facebook return url. Algorithm for detection is:

1. Facebook URL pattern: `fb1106884526040279://authorize/...` with `fb1106884526040279` is your app id. So you just need to check if this url start with your app id, is host equals to `authorize` (the string after `//` and first `/`)
2. Google URL Pattern: `com.googleusercontent.apps.803921065829-m34o26vcj57oirk1oa8pqve5o22qdihn` So you just need to check if this url start with `com.googleusercontent.apps`.

Base on above explanation, I have generalized into `GoogleAuth` and `FacebookAuth` utils class with some small methods such as logout, check login ...

Here is  `Google Authentication Utils`

```
import Google

class GoogleAuth {

    static func getInstance() -> GIDSignIn {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    }

    static func isLogin() -> Bool {
        return getInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()
    }

    static func signOut() {
        getInstance().signOut()
    }

    static func isValidatedWithUrl(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        return url.scheme.hasPrefix(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!) || url.scheme.hasPrefix("com.googleusercontent.apps.")
    }
}
```

Secondly is `Facebook Authentication Utils`

```
import FBSDKLoginKit

class FacebookAuth {
    static func isLogin() -> Bool {
       return FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil
    }

    static func signOut() {
       FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
    }

    static func isValidatedWithUrl(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        return url.scheme.hasPrefix("fb\(FBSDKSettings.appID())") && url.host == "authorize"
    }
}
```

Here is the main part. In `AppDelegate`, you call `isValidateWithUrl` method for checking if this url is from Google or Facebook.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        print("step 2 of OAuth2. Url: \(url)")

        // url from google
        if GoogleAuth.isValidatedWithUrl(url) {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(
                    url,
                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
        }
        // url from facebook
         else if FacebookAuth.isValidatedWithUrl(url) {
             return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                    openURL: url,
                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String,
                    annotation: options [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
        }
        // application hasn't supported this url yet
        else {
              return false
        }
    }
```

Hope this help :)